# Let $x=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{...}}}}$; then the value of $(2x-1)^2$ equals...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, continued-fractions

Let $$x=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{...}}}};$$ then the value of $(2x-1)^2$ equals...

I don't how to start this question. Please help.

Comment: Hint: Is there a pattern to the fraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to know the value that the continued fraction converges to, you use a simple technique:

$$
x=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{...}}}}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{x}}
$$

With some manipulation you could come up with the value of $x$, but you want $(2x-1)^2:$

$$
x\left(2+\frac{1}{x} \right)=\left(2+\frac{1}{x} \right)+1
$$

$$
2x+1=3+\frac{1}{x}
$$

Multiply everything by $x$, since we know it's not zero:

$$
2x^2-2x-1=0
$$

Complete the square that we want by multiplying by $2$:
$$
4x^2-4x-2=4x^2-4x+1-3=(2x-1)^2-3=0
$$

Hence the answer is 3.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**:

Write the expression as $$x=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{x}}.$$